# Bulk Updating a nested field based on a nested filter (Initial issue resolved but facing new issue)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I need to update a nested field that is filtered by another nested field in parent.child nested object. Once I get this working I'll be using a CRON scheduler of sorts to automate/trigger this function.

My main schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const { requestDetailSchema } = require("./requestDetail");
const { packDetailSchema } = require("./packDetail");
const { PermitDetailSchema } = require("../certificates/PermitDetail");

const { JHADetailSchema } = require("../certificates/JHADetail");
const { ALCDetailSchema } = require("../certificates/ALCDetail");
const .... etc.

const packSchema = new Schema({
  requestDetail: requestDetailSchema,
  packDetail: packDetailSchema, // < --- by a filter found in here
  permitDetail: PermitDetailSchema, // < --- Need to update object here

  jhaDetail: JHADetailSchema,
  alcDetail: ALCDetailSchema,
  ... etc.

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Pack", packSchema);
```

The required sub schema that I'm needing to update is the below:
packDetailSchema statusDetail:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const packDetailSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    status: { type: String },
    code: { type: String },
    statusDetail: [ //<--- update doc to include below fields.
      {
        id: { type: Number }, 
        code: { type: String },
        name: { type: String },
        description: { type: String },
      },
    ],

    authorisationDetail: {
      id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
      name: { type: String },
      department: { type: String },
      contactPhone: { type: String },
      email: { type: String },
      refIndicator: { type: String },
      position: {
        id: { type: Number },
        name: { type: String },
      },
    },
  },
  { _id: false, timestamps: true }
);

exports.packDetailSchema = packDetailSchema;
```

My filter by is in the PermitDetail gasTestRequirementDetail.gasTestFrequencyDetail.id = 3   schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PermitDetailSchema = new Schema(
  {
     ...
        other nested objects here
     ...
    gasTestRequirementDetail: [
      {
        id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId },
        name: { type: String },
        code: { type: String },
        sortOrder: { type: Number },
        filterBy: { type: String },
      },
    ],
    gasTestFrequencyDetail: {
      id: { type: Number }, // <-- filtering all documents based on id = 3
      name: { type: String }, // <-- name = "3 hr"
    },
    
... more objects etc.
   
  },

  { _id: false, timestamps: true }
);

exports.PermitDetailSchema = PermitDetailSchema;
```

My "gasTestFrequencyDetail" object holds an id of any one of the following
id 3 name 3 hrs,
id 6 name 6 hrs
id 12 name 12 hrs

I need to filter for example all documents based on

```
"permitDetail.gasTestFrequencyDetail.id": 3
```

My function is as below:

```
const expireGasTests = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const filter = {
      "permitDetail.gasTestFrequencyDetail.id": 3,
      // packDetail: { id: "63fc3165790e88394efbd5ed" },
      // "packDetail.statusDetail": { $elemMatch: { code: "REQ_AUTHORISED" } // <--- if I uncomment the above line and as long as there is an element
// match of the above, the update works, but as soon as I try //"permitDetail.gasTestFrequencyDetail.id": 3 I get my HttpError
  },
    };

// need to filter all documents by above criteria and update the document with the below object 
    const updateDoc = {
      $set: {
        "packDetail.statusDetail.$.id": 19,
        "packDetail.statusDetail.$.code": "PMT_GASTESTNEEDED",
        "packDetail.statusDetail.$.name": "Gas Test Needed",
        "packDetail.statusDetail.$.description":
          "Gas test has expired and will need retesting.",
      },
    };
    await Pack.updateMany(filter, updateDoc).then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Gas Tests Expired.", result });
    });

  } catch (err) {
    return next(
      new HttpError("Something failed. Please check your form data", 500)
    );
  }
};
```

How do I code this up to filter all documents where "Gas Test Expires" every 3 hrs and update the packDetail.statusDetail with the appropriate $set code?

PS It works if I uncomment the

```
"packDetail.statusDetail": { $elemMatch: { code: "REQ_AUTHORISED" } },
```

but as soon as i step out of the current child nest into the parent.child nest I hit my HttpError.

Hope I've detailed my issue correctly. Please reach out if you need more info or explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Updates:
I've managed to get the correct document to update, along with its appropriate object via the below code.

However, if a document does not have an entry for "packDetail.statusDetail", I get...

```
"MongoServerError: The path 'packDetail.statusDetail' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates."
```

How would I change my below code to cater for non existent array?

My new function:

```
const HttpError = require("../../models/utils/http-error");

const Pack = require("../../models/packs/pack");

const expireGasTests = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const filter = {
      "permitDetail.gasTestFrequencyDetail.id": 3,
    };

    const update = {
      $set: {
        "packDetail.statusDetail.$[element].id": 5,
        "packDetail.statusDetail.$[element].code": "PMT_GASTESTNEEDED",
        "packDetail.statusDetail.$[element].name": "Gas Test Needed",
        "packDetail.statusDetail.$[element].description":
          "Gas test has expired and will need retesting.",
      },
    };

    const options = {
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          "element.code": "PMT_GASTESTNEEDED",
        },
      ],
      multi: true,
    };

    await Pack.updateMany(filter, update, options).then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Gas Tests Expired.", result });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new HttpError(err, 500));
  }
};

exports.expireGasTests = expireGasTests;
```